# Using doc(doc.id).snapshots/get(), isn`t working in StreamBuilder

Tags: firebase, flutter, stream, cloud

StreamBuilder throwing an argument type error when i use
`stream:FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('collection).doc(doc.id).snapshots(),`

how can i use doc(doc.id) in stream?
i tried using "`where`" keyword but its not working either.

Error: `The argument type 'Stream<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Stream<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>?'`

Comment: Please include code for entire `StreamBuilder`, it is hard to help with these details.

Comment: Solved it i was using StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot> i changed it to StreamBuilder()